# Sending object over socket - object contains bufferedimage- Any ideas?

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedimage

Im sending a object over a socket, an object of the following class:

```
public class ClientDetail implements Serializable{
public String username;
public String [] capturedText;
public String site;
public BufferedImage screenShot; 
 }
```

and I am trying to send it using the following:

```
        ClientDetail cD = new ClientDetail();
        cD.capturedText = mon.getCapturedText();
        cD.username = username;
        cD.site = mon.getWebsite();
        ScreenShot ss = new ScreenShot();
        cD.screenShot = ss.getScreenShot();

        if(mon.isCaptured)
        {
            try{
                output.writeObject(cD);
                output.flush(); 
            }catch(IOException ex){
                System.out.println("\nSomething messed up sending the message!");
            }
        }
```

This is failing to send.  Can you send an object that contains a image over a socket?

Comment: What error message did you get? / What was the exception? If you are just swallowing `ex`, then its no wonder that you do not know what goes wrong.

Comment: ava.io.NotSerializableException: java.awt.image.BufferedImage
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
 at client.Client.whileConnected(Client.java:76)
 at client.Client.startRunning(Client.java:31)
 at client.ClientMain.main(ClientMain.java:8)

Comment: I knew it had something to do with the bufferedimage, as u use a different method to write a image over a socket. (Im a a newbie btw..go easy lol)

Comment: because the bufferedimage isnt serializable i will probably just have to send it separate.. or do u know of a way to make it serializable?

Comment: Write the BufferedImage to an ByteArrayOutputStream using the method shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12674109/3080094), remove BufferedImage from ClientDetail and add the byte-array. Byte arrays are Serializable.

Comment: Yeah thats what I ended up doing. thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Send thing:

`ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) image, "png", output);`

Receiver thing you know:

`ImageIO.read(input);`

Comment: please [add more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to explain more about how this accomplishes what the OP is asking, so that the OP *understands why* this will help