# How to save image that user selected and save into a folder in my desktop

Tags: java, image, swing, jfilechooser, filechooser

i would like to know on how to save a image that user selected previously. I only know how to allow user to select image.

This is my current code I have.

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        // String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
        //jTextField1.setText(filename);
        try {
            ImageIcon ii=new ImageIcon(scaleImage(120, 120, ImageIO.read(new File(f.getAbsolutePath()))));//get the image from file chooser and scale it to match JLabel size
            jLabel3.setIcon(ii);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static BufferedImage scaleImage(int w, int h, BufferedImage img) throws Exception {
        BufferedImage bi;
        bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.createGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, null);
        g2d.dispose();
        return bi;
    }
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674064/how-to-save-a-bufferedimage-as-a-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
BufferedImage img = ...; 
String location = ...; 
String format = ...; // "PNG" for example
ImageIO.write(img, format, new File(location));
```

Comment: It's better to use the original bytes of the image file.  Using `ImageIO` will often change the (file) size of the image and if JPEG, will likely save it at a different compression/quality level.

Comment: Wouldn't using streams for this task complicate it much?

Comment: Define 'much'..  BTW - have you tried altering the compression of a JPEG?  It isn't rocket science, but not far from it.  Check out the `getJpegCompressedImage(BufferedImage image)` method on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5998015/418556). And note that there is no way within `ImageIO` to know what compression/quality was used in the original image..

Comment: "Isn't rocket science"-Yeah, right. I'm going to make an educated guess the OP wants nothing to do with image compression =P

Comment: Thank you so much!