# How to save BufferedImage object to file?

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedimage

I'm trying to save a png image but I can't get the image to be created, despite [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674064/how-to-save-a-bufferedimage-as-a-file).

I'm using selenium webDriver to take a screenshot of the chrome browser window, the `getScreenshotAs()` returns a byte array that I put into a `ByteArrayInputStream` object. I also have a rectangle `view` that contains the dimensions I want to crop the image to, using `getSubimage()`.

with the code provided below, no image is created, when I add `imgfile.createNewFile()` a file is created but is entirely empty and does not register as a 'png' file.

Essentially all I want to do is take an image that I have in memory as a byte array, crop it to specific dimensions, and save it as a png file. Really basic I know but I can't quite figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```java
ByteArrayInputStream imgbytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES));
BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(imgbytes);

bimg = bimg.getSubimage(view.getX(), view.getY(), view.getWidth(), view.getWidth());

File imgfile = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\newimg.png");
ImageIO.write(bimg, "png", imgfile);
```

Comment: You are sure that 'new ByteArrayInputStream(((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES));' is provding you with some data?

You might want to post that code as well.

Comment: Not sure the issue is with the "saving" of the image, it's more likely with the generation, but it's impossible to know based on the out of context code

Comment: @MadProgrammer I apologize for the lack of context, I have edited the question to provide some more details. Please let me know if there's anything else I can add that will help.

Comment: `ImageIO.write(...)` returns a `boolean` indicating whether the image was written or not. What is the value in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your code sample and I am able to get a screenshot. Because I don't have a `view` variable, just hardcoded some valid values as follows:

```
ByteArrayInputStream imgbytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES));
assert imgbytes.available() > 0;
BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(imgbytes);
bimg = bimg.getSubimage(0, 0, 500, 500);
assert bimg.getHeight() > 0;
assert bimg.getWidth() > 0;
File imgfile = new File("screenshot.png");
ImageIO.write(bimg, "png", imgfile);
assert imgfile.length() > 0;
```

You should add the assertion lines and figure out where the stream is being interrupted, but my guess would be that: 1) there is some problem with the `view` variable and providing invalid values, 2) the output file `imgfile` cannot be written (check for permissions, a correct path, etc)